# Unable to get mvc webapi bearer token after hosting on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm working on the securing the web API by OAuth bearer token as this working fine in local able to generate token, After hosting on server code is not working to generate token hosted on the server.

when am trying to the server sample Url "api.somedemo.com/token" showing the request responce as **method not found** ,

but in local "**http://local:1234/token**" same code working generated token.

I can't able find where am missing on the server to able generate bearer token.

here the code.
From Controller:

```
private BearerToken GetBearerToken(string userName, string password)
  {
            BearerToken token = null;

            FormUrlEncodedContent bearerTokenContent = OAuthClientWrapper.CreateBearerToken(userName, password);
            Uri tokenUri = new Uri("api.somedemo.com/token");
            token = OAuthClientWrapper.GetJwtToken(tokenUri, bearerTokenContent);

            return token;
        }
```

OAuthClientWrapper Class:

```
public static FormUrlEncodedContent CreateBearerToken(string userName, string password)
        {
            var bearerTokenContent = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            };

            return new FormUrlEncodedContent(bearerTokenContent);
        }
```

GetJwtToken method:

```
public static BearerToken GetJwtToken(Uri uri, FormUrlEncodedContent bearerTokenContent)
        {
            BearerToken token = null;

            try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Set the headers
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, bearerTokenContent).Result)
                    {
                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            token = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<BearerToken>().Result;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var reasonPhrase = response.ReasonPhrase;
                            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            var errorMessage = string.Format("Error: {0} {1} for uri: {2}", reasonPhrase, result, uri.AbsoluteUri);
                            //Log the error message
                            token = null;
                        } //else
                    } //using
                }//using
            }//try
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {

                throw aex;
            }//catch

            return token;
        }
```

As WebAPI Startup Class:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtOptions());
        }
    }
```

Startupoverride :

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }


        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            int tokenExpiration = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpiration"]);

            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                 AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                 Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                //AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(audience, new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, signingKey)),
                AccessTokenFormat = new MyJwtFormat(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new ApplicationRefreshTokenProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenExpiration)

            };
            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
```

Application OAuthProviderClass:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;
        IHttpClientWrapper _HttpClientWrapper = null;
        private IEndPoints _ConfigsProviders = null;


        public ApplicationOAuthProvider()
        {
            _HttpClientWrapper = new HttpClientWrapper();
            _ConfigsProviders = new EndPoints();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                var isValidUser = false;
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

                var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "someAPIBaseUrl", context.UserName, context.Password);
                //Getting user information if login is validated in json format.
                var returnValue = _HttpClientWrapper.GetStringAsync(url);

                var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(returnValue);
                if (responseObject.Status==true)
                {
                    isValidUser = true;
                }

                if (!isValidUser)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
                context.Validated(identity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }


        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }


        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
            {
                Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

                if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
                {
                    context.Validated();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "userName", userName }
            };
            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }

    }





   public MyJwtFormat()
            {
                _tokenIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenIssuer"];
                _tokenExpiration = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpiration"]);
            }
```

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenIssuer"] given  "localhost" in sever also.

Please help to fix this issue

Advance thanks you.

Comment: I did not got any reply thanks

Comment: I found it the answer